# Rendering a single HTML page on a private Bitbucket server

Tags: html, bitbucket

My company has an internal, private Bitbucket server where all of the companies repositories are hosted. Of course, only people in the company, logged into their company account, can access this private Bitbucket domain.

I have a single .html file which I want to store/host on this private Bitbucket server, so that anyone in my company can view the html file rendered fully, rather than in its raw form.

Is this possible? If so how can I do it?

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid this is not possible with the standard **Bitbucket Server** functionality.

[A suggestion to implement it](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BSERV-4099) was raised long ago back in 2013.
It is yet not satisfied.

The last official update was in Dec 2016. In short, they don't see it as a priority and instead recommend to use the 3rd-party add-on - [Pages for Bitbucket Server](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1212525/pages-for-bitbucket-server?hosting=server&tab=overview). Which, I guess, is not what people were looking for.

Anyways, the situation stays the same for 2021.

I'm also interested in such functionality and will be glad to find other alternatives.